# Problem with connection to FIX counterparty

Tags: python, connection, quickfix, fix-protocol, stunnel

I am trying to connect to my counterparty's FIX

For fix connection I am using **quickfix** with **python**. Here is my *settings.config* for quickfix (*SenderCompId*, *TargetCompId*, *port* and *host* received from counterparty):

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
FileStorePath=C:\Users\me\Desktop\fix\store
FileLogPath=C:\Users\me\Desktop\fix\log
SenderCompID=sendid
[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
ResetOnLogon=Y
StartTime=21:05:00
EndTime=21:03:00
TargetCompID=targid
HeartBtInt=30
SocketConnectPort=port
SocketConectHost=ip
DataDictionary=C:\Users\me\Desktop\fix\FIX44.xml
```

Here is the code of my simple application. I am trying at first to send a **Logon** message to my counterparty (*password* also received from counterparty):

```
class App(fix.Application):
    def onCreate(self, sessionID):
        print('on create')
        return
    def onLogon(self, sessionID):
        self.sessionID = sessionID
        print("Success Logon to session '%s'.", sessionID.toString())
        return
    def onLogout(self, sessionID):
        print('on logout')
        return
    def toAdmin(self, message, sessionID):
        print('to admin')
        if message.getHeader().getField(35) == 'A':
            message.setField(554, 'password')
        print(message.toString())
        return
    def toApp(self, message, sessionID):
        print("Receive message \n", message.toString())
        return
    def fromAdmin(self, message, sessionID):
        print('from admin')
        return
    def fromApp(self, message, sessionID):
        print('from app')
        return

settings = fix.SessionSettings('settings.config')
storeFactory = fix.SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory)
initiator.start()
print('initiator start')
```

The output of my app is as follows (problems with fix message separator while copy):

```
on create
initiator start
```

In my log path after `initiator.start()` creates four `.txt` files. Their names are:

```
FIX.4.4-sendid-targid.event.current.log
FIX.4.4-sendid-targid.messages.current.log
GLOBAL.event.current.log
GLOBAL.messages.current.log
```

In `FIX.4.4-sendid-targid.event.current.log` creates a message:
`date-time: Created session`
, all other are empty.

As you see, I am trying to send Logon message to my counterparty. However, I **do not receive any output about successful Logon**. Counterparty also does not see any connection from my side.

What could be the problem? I seem to do everything according to the rules.
Please help.

Comment: I suspect (a) your counterparty has not whitelisted your IP where your connection comes from so your logon message doesn't get through their network to their FIX engine, and (b) you are stopping your initiatior immediately after starting it. You don't need the `initiator.stop()`

Comment: (a) I used minifix from elato.se in order to check if there is any connection between my and my counterparty and it was successful. So using minifix soft I can establish a logon and receive an appropriate answer. So the problem I guess is somewhere in my quickfix application itself and I still cannot solve it.

(b) Checked it before, did not help.

Comment: 1. Did you double check your CompIDs? 2. Don't send a Logon by yourself. The Initiator will do it for you.

Comment: Did you comment on this? There was a notification but I can see no comment. Maybe deleted?

Comment: Sorry, accidently removed it.

Comment: So do you mean I have to delete my `send_logon` function and not call it in after `initiator.start()`? If that, I receive only `'on create', 'initiator start', 'initiator stop'` in my output. Don't now how to solve it... Yes, I checked my ids hundred times.

Comment: 1. As rupweb said you shouldn't stop your initiator right after starting it. 2. When you remove the stop what is the content of the files in your `FileLogPath`?

Comment: More strange things: `554` shouldn't be set in the header but in the body. You set it in the header in `toAdmin()`. You do not need to set the other fields there. QuickFIX will do that from your settings.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have changed my code as you said in the following way: all functions in `App` are now empty, except `toAdmin`: it has only `if message.getHeader().getField(35) == 'A': message.setField(554, 'password')`. I also leaved only `initiator.start()` and `print(initiator start)` in main part. In my output I receive messages `on create` (from Apps's `onCreate` function) and `initiator start`.

Comment: In my log path after `initiator.start()` creates four `.txt` files. Their names are: `FIX.4.4-sendid-targid.event.current.log`, `FIX.4.4-sendid-targid.messages.current.log`, `GLOBAL.event.current.log` and `GLOBAL.messages.current.log`. In `FIX.4.4-sendid-targid.event.current.log` creates a message `date-time: Created session`. All other are empty.

Comment: *Changed my question with new code and output version

Comment: So as I can see, somehow **quickfix does not send a logon message**, since where is no `to admin` in the output

Comment: Yes, and the log file is empty. So my assumption is that it cannot connect to the opposite side. Can you verify that the initiator at least connects to your stunnel? Can you telnet through the stunnel?

Comment: I am also asking myself if the start and end time confuse QuickFIX since the `StartTime` is after the `EndTime`. Could you maybe check with an interval of e.g. `StartTime=00:00:00` till `EndTime=23:59:00`

Comment: I asked my counterparty for direct connection to exclude all possible problems with stunnel. I received *ip* and *port* for connection. Edited my question. But the problem is still the same, so I guess in previous version it was in app itself. Still can't solve it...

Comment: As for **StartTime** and **EndTime**: changed it as you recommended, but still didn't help. These exact time values are written in my counterparty's fix documentation, so I wrote them as base (they are different from ones in the previous version, but still same ordered.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, sorry. Your config looks pretty standard to me and should cause no problems. The only thing that still looks a bit odd to me is that you configured the `SenderCompID` in the `DEFAULT` section. But it should still work anyway. Maybe you can play around a little with the settings, e.g. create a second `SESSION` that is completely using own settings, i.e. that overwrites all settings in the `DEFAULT` section to rule out any weird bugs that might exist in the implementation of the code that deals with the settings.

Comment: So you think the App structure is OK, right? Wasn't I mistaken in **SocketConnectionPort** and **SocketConnectionPort**: I have to use my counterparty's values? A weird question, but maybe...

Comment: I just realized that your setting for the host misses an "n". It should be called `SocketConnectHost` NOT SocketCo**n**ectHost. But actually I would expect that the app reports an error when that setting isn't there.